# Recovering overwritten file git after force merge

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, data-recovery, git-revert

I am really disappointed, I have lost all my files I have been working for a few days. And the problem that I've just realized that.

I don't even remember what I did then to overwrite all my local changes.

I missed important files, only I have is the following `git log`

[image]

I cannot find any of my files. Only one thing I remember is that I when I made commits and tried to push to remote `git push --all` it always showed me that `Everything is up to date` after that I did something really terrible and I cannot remember what I did, resulting in the lost files. I executed some git commands, maybe with the flag `-f`, but I didn't remove anything manually, only git commands.

I've already tried `git log -p app/controller/somefile.js`

Please suggest what can I do to recover my files.

Comment: This diagram does not really show us much (branches, hashes, etc....) can you do a `git log --graph --all --decorate --oneline` and put the output up on your question. It sounds like your files may have been committed at some point - if so they should be retrievable by checking out a previous commit - I assume one before the merge, but we'll need to see the hashes and/or branch names to see what to checkout. Probably you want to checkout the commit that is described as "Add dumps" to look for your files...

Comment: Also print out the output of `git status` just to see what (if any) modded files are kicking around....

Comment: @code_fodder thanks for the answer, but there are no any of these files there

Comment: Did you checkout that commit? (`git checkout <hash>`)?

Comment: What about sharing your history of commands execution, maybe we could help from there. Try executing: "history" in your shell.

Comment: Thanks all for answers, but there no such file in the history at all, I have tried to check every commit

Comment: it seems that I forced overwrote the local branch with the remote one ....